# Grouping the records

Tags: sql, oracle, count, group-by

I have a vehicle_fact table with the fields start_Date_Time, end_date_time, location and driver_id. My objective is to get the stopage count, its start date, end date based on driver_id and location.

The table is as follows,

```
start_Date_Time          end_date_time            LOCATION  driver_id
---------------          -------------            --------  ---------
11/08/2013 06:51:53      11/08/2013 07:06:50         loc1        2
11/08/2013 09:00:15      11/08/2013 09:16:37         loc2        2
11/08/2013 09:41:16      11/08/2013 09:50:03         loc1        2
11/08/2013 09:53:28      11/08/2013 10:01:27         loc1        2
11/08/2013 10:41:31      11/08/2013 10:45:45         loc2        2
11/08/2013 11:25:54      11/08/2013 11:38:55         loc1        2
11/08/2013 14:45:08      11/08/2013 14:54:52         loc2        3
11/08/2013 15:20:45      11/08/2013 15:28:29         loc2        3
11/08/2013 15:30:39      11/08/2013 15:31:59         loc1        3
11/08/2013 16:25:24      11/08/2013 16:25:35         loc1        3
11/08/2013 20:26:35      12/08/2013 01:51:19         loc1        3
```

The desired result should be:

```
start_Date_Time          end_date_time            LOCATION  driver_id count
11/08/2013 06:51:53      11/08/2013 07:06:50      loc1      2         1
11/08/2013 09:00:15      11/08/2013 09:16:37      loc2      2         1
11/08/2013 09:41:16      11/08/2013 10:01:27      loc1      2         2
11/08/2013 10:41:31      11/08/2013 10:45:45      loc2      2         1
11/08/2013 11:25:54      11/08/2013 11:38:55      loc1      2         1
11/08/2013 14:45:08      11/08/2013 15:28:29      loc2      3         2
11/08/2013 15:30:39      12/08/2013 01:51:19      loc1      3         3
```

Is it possible to do it in an SQL.

Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: Whatever logic you have used in your front end can be framed in `Stored Procedure`. Sorry I am not a converter.

Comment: what do you mean by stopage count?

Comment: Hi Bew, It's vehicle idle count(when the ignition is off).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this query the inner subquery `GRP` counts records before the current with different `Driver_id` or `Location` so for the same `Driver_id,Location` records followed one by one we get the same GRP count. then we just group by `Driver_id,Location` and GRP.

```
select min(START_DATE_TIME),
       Max(END_DATE_TIME),
       LOCATION,
       DRIVER_ID,
       count(*) cnt
FROM
(
select t1.*,
(select count(*) 
  from vehicle_fact t2
  where (t2.End_date_time<t1.End_date_time)
    and 
    (
     (t2.location<>t1.location)
      OR
     (t2.driver_id <>t1.driver_id )
    )  
) Grp

from vehicle_fact t1
) T3

GROUP BY LOCATION,DRIVER_ID,GRP
  order by min(START_DATE_TIME)
```

[SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9bdfa/7)

Answer (score -1):

```
select start_Date_Time, end_date_time, LOCATION, driver_id
,    (select count(*) 
      from table t2
      where
           t1.driver_id=t2.driver_id
      and  t1.LOCATION=t2.LOCATION
      )
from table t1
order by t1.driver_id asc
```

may be like that, if i correct understand u.